# Symfony2: How to pass parameters to form collections

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using a form(parent form) with a collection field type(child forms). Each type in the collection is a form that contains some choice fields, I want to filter this field choices using query_builder parameter for join with other entities ect. I know how to pass parameters to parent form from controller, but how to pass parameters to each item in the collection (child forms)?

Comment: By "parameters" do you mean the `$options` array that's passed to `buildForm()`?

Comment: Here is something worth trying out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20229988/583786

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a data transformer.  The data transformer takes data from your sub forms allows you to do queries to the database from inside it and pass 1 final result out the end.  I had to do this the other day with country and postal code to find a valid postal code in a country.

Here's the link to the cookbook info that will show you how to use it.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223519/1756517

In each form, pass the variable by the construct method ($form = new FormType($your_variable);)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late response, but with Symfony3, you should use the `entry_options` parameter [as mentioned here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options). It was exactly what I needed, in scenario similar to yours.